# How to Create user objects with CreateAPIView in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i need create class with CreateAPIView  for create new object

```
class Register(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes=(AllowAny)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def perform_create (self,serializer):
        obj = serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return Response({
                "id": obj.id,
                "username": obj.username,

        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content_type='application/json')
```

but this code dosent work and And shows the following error :

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

url my code:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import  Register 

urlpatterns = [

    path('register/', Register)
]


What should I do?
```

Comment: my guess is `permission_classes`  needs to be a tuple, ie `permission_classes=(AllowAny,)` instead of `(AllowAny)` (notice the comma)

Comment: Share your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `urls.py` (you missed the `as_view()` )

You have to write your path like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', Register.as_view())
]
```